# parsing rss from the end

Tags: php, parsing, rss

```
<?
$rss = simplexml_load_file($url);
if ($rss) {
foreach ($rss->channel->item as $str) {
echo '<p>".$str->title."</p>';
}
}
?>
```

I want to make output from end of RSS to beginning. How should I do this?

Answer (score 1):

I assume that `$rss` is an array, in that case you can use the [`array_reverse()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reverse.php) function :

```
foreach (array_reverse($rss->channel->item) as $str) {
    echo '<p>'.$str->title.'</p>';
}
```